# Polar Represantation of Shifted Disk

Tags: circles, polar-coordinates

How to represent a shifted circle or disk (I mean the center of the circle is not at origin) in polar coordinate?

For example I have a circle/disk in z-Domain like this:
[image]

I thought this:

> $z = re^{j\theta}$;

subject to:

> $0 < r < 2$   and  $-\pi/2<\theta<\pi/2$

But I think it isn' t right.

Comment: I think something along the lines of $z = 1 + re^{i \theta}$ should work. Is j supposed to be 2? If that's the case,$ 0 \leq r \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \theta  < 2 \pi$.

Comment: @John - j means i (imaginary). Your approach is fine for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the centre of the circle is $r_oe^{i\theta_o}$. If we want a circle of radius $c$, it is given by $2-2rr_ocos(\theta-\theta_o)=c^2$.